# mysql partition by range performance on a date column

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Need advise on partitioning my database tables. The table has 12M rows.

I currently built the following partitions. Resulted in great performance increase on my queries.

```
ALTER TABLE sales_data_mkt
PARTITION BY RANGE ( TO_DAYS(`ACTIVITY_DT`) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DAYS('2015-01-01') ),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DAYS('2015-02-01') ),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DAYS('2015-03-01') ),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DAYS('2015-04-01') ),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ( TO_DAYS('2015-05-01') ),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

After doing all this i saw that you can also partition without the `To_DAYS()` method using `Partition by Range columns`

```
ALTER TABLE sales_data_mkt
PARTITION BY RANGE columns (`ACTIVITY_DT`) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-01-01'),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-02-01'),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-03-01'),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-04-01'),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-05-01'),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
```

What are the pro/cons for the new `range columns` way of partitioning. Is it faster?

Comment: In MySQL partitioning is usually not done for better performance and 12M records is not so much to really need it. Did you just miss the proper indexes before?

Comment: i have covering indexes that seem good. Why would you not benefit from partitioning in mysql. What is the purpose other than performance?

Comment: Usually it is used to quickly remove the old data - `drop partition` is fast and frees the space where delete is slow and does not free the disk space without optimize - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots#partitioning

Comment: I doubt if there is any difference.  Can you provide `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT` for each version?